# Can OS work without kernel?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, gnu

I am interested in history of creating a GNU/Linux and how did these two operating systems unified.

So, there was GNU, and it needed a kernel. They were developing their own kernel called "GNU Heart". But Richard Stallman said that he didn't like it. Then he found out that there was Linux, and then these two operating systems unified. So, my question is:

- How could GNU work without kernel before they unified with Linux?

Or maybe I miss something?

Comment: I suppose you meant GNU Hurd.

Comment: There are a lot of misconceptions here. GNU is not an OS. They did not "unify".

Comment: Yeah and I'd be surprised if Stallmann ever said he preferred Linux over Hurd. This question is full of misunderstanding and questionable claims.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU applications couldn't indeed run without a kernel. v.g. without anything capable of performing system calls, interfacing with the hardware…

The **[libc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library)** enabling the interface between application programs and system calls (in kernel progams) was the key element.
libc was already compatible with many systems when Stallman started his GNU project in the early 80s.